# Is it wrong if one Aggregate references other Aggregates Entity?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

For example,

```
public class Company:IAggregateRoot {
  public CompanyId Id;
  public ReadonlyCollection<Office> _offices;
  ...
}

public class EquipmentPiece {
  public EquipmentPieceId Id;
  private CompanyId _companyId;
  private OfficeId _officeId;
  ...
}
```

So, there is logic that needs to be checked when new `Office` is being added to the `Company` and that's done through `Company` aggregate (as it depends on other properties on `Company`).
On the other hand, each `EquipmentPiece` has to have a reference to the `Office` where they are installed.

I want to avoid having the whole tree within a single aggregate (`Company.Office.EquipmentPiece`).

Is there anything conceptually wrong doing it this way?

Answer (score 1):

As described by Evans in 2003, entities in an aggregate may have a reference to the *root entity* of another aggregate.

In a relational data model, that would normally end up looking like having a foreign key, that would be used to look up the second aggregate root (Office) when reloading the primary (Company).

Today, I would guess you are more likely to see the id of the second root, rather than a reference to the root itself:

```
public class Company:IAggregateRoot {
  public CompanyId Id;
  public Collection<OfficeId> _offices;
  ...
}
```

Comment: yes, that's alright.  but `Office` is not a root entity but a simple entity governed by `Company` aggregate. Question is, should another aggregate `EquipmentPiece` hold a reference to `Office`?

Comment: You should only be able to "reach" domain entities via their aggregate roots and traversal.

Comment: The benefits of the pattern come from accepting its constraints.

Comment: Could you please say a word about what is the reason behind that "rule"/pattern?

Answer (score 1):

You're right, referencing by identity is something fairly common. Some objects live as either entities or value objects within the boundaries of a particular aggregate and are referenced by identity in another aggregate. No DDD police will come haunt you :-)

Do consider that you could write something like `aCompany.Install(aPieceOfEquipment, atOfficeOfCompany)` to help make sure that you're installing equipment at a known company office (at least at the time you're telling). Do consider that this does not match reality: either you express the intent for a piece of equipment to be installed at an office at a certain point in time *or* you express the fact that a piece of equipment *has* been installed at an office. Do consider that before a piece of equipment is installed it's still a piece of equipment not yet installed at any office. I'm not implying that the model that you build needs to take this into account - picking the most useful model is the job.

Comment: you are completely right in your observations and indeed, my model does take it into an account...i've just posted simplified version here that illustrates particular dillema. but sure, piece of equipment is a piece of equipment, installed or not. one of its characteristics is that it *can* be installed to a particular office at particular time. really appreciate your thoughts!